# How to send private message to user on Telegram using his @username and not chat id

Tags: php, telegram-bot, sendmessage

I am making a cron job in PHP that will send some text message to users on Telegram at certain intervals.

I am using following to send message to user which is working fine. But the problem is this method only sends message to user via `chat_id`.

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY_TOKEN>/sendMessage?text=ok&chat_id=12345678
```

When I try to use username then I get error:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY_TOKEN>/sendMessage?text=ok&chat_id=@username
```

**Error:**
Bad Request: chat not found

Even if I use `username` and not `@username` it results in same issue. I know that user must send message to bot first before bot can send message to user. I have already done it that's why I am able to send message using `chat_id`. But how do I send message using @username?

Or may be there is a way to get chat_id of a user via telegram API? If that is the case then I can call that method first and then call sendMessage method. But I don't know any such API.

Comment: Save a record in your database of which username corresponds to which chat ID.

Comment: Does your bot already have an existing chat started with this user?

Comment: @esqew Yes....and that is not an issue...issue is sending message directly using `@username`

Comment: @FrankMartin Since you're passing this value as part of a URL parameter, certain rules about the content of the parameters themselves have to be taken into account - specifically, [`@` has a special meaning in certain parts of URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2). Have you tried replacing the `@` with its URL-escaped counterpart `%40`?

Comment: As a side note, it seems like you're not using any sort of [Telegram API wrapper library](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples#php); why not? The abstraction of these types of calls can make your life significantly easier.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about them. But I am old school and don't want to use any wrapper if the original API is available. Besides my main use case is just to send message and nothing else.